# How to call a php function from ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I am familiar of how to get ajax to go to a php page an execute a series of things and then return json data. However is it possible to call a specific function which resides in a given page?

Basically what I want is to reduce the number of files in a project. So I can put a lot of common functions in one page and then just call whatever the function that I want at the moment.

Comment: yes you can. just add some flag in current url for ajax request. like your current url ?isAjax = 1 and in script check that flag

Comment: yes you can do that. You have to just take care about parameters , so that call to a function can distinguish from each other. in php you can use switch cases (not always required) based on these parameter to distinguish the function

Comment: mvc pattern would have help, another way is to call the functions based on the parameters passed in url.. iF ELSE clauses on a parameter and call the respective function

Comment: You may use the routing approach that is provided by various frameworks. For instance, [slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/)

Comment: I've built a fairly large project without a backend framework, I figure I probably should have now. I think when I complete the majority of it and I have some time spare, I'll convert it across.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For AJAX request

1. Include jQuery Library in your web page.
   For e.g.

   ```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Call a function on button click

   ```
   <button type="button" onclick="create()">Click Me</button>
   ```
3. While click on button, call create function in JavaScript.

   ```
   <script>
       function create () {
           $.ajax({
               url:"test.php",    //the page containing php script
               type: "post",    //request type,
               dataType: 'json',
               data: {registration: "success", name: "xyz", email: "abc@gmail.com"},
               success:function(result){
                   console.log(result.abc);
               }
           });
       }
   </script>
   ```

On the server side test.php file, the action POST parameter should be read and the corresponding value and do the action in PHP and return in JSON format e.g.

```
$registration = $_POST['registration'];
$name= $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];

if ($registration == "success"){
    // some action goes here under php
    echo json_encode(array("abc"=>'successfuly registered'));
}
```

Comment: I am confused that why he accepted your answer. He is asking to call a particular php function from ajax and you are calling a javascript function.

Answer (score 23):

**You cannot call a PHP function directly from an AJAX request, but you can do this instead:**

```
<? php 
    function test($data){
        return $data+1;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['callFunc1'])) {
        echo test($_POST['callFunc1']);
    }
?>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myFunctions.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { "callFunc1": "1"},
        success: function(response) { console.log(response); }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach because the response will include everything not just the result of echoing the function

Answer (score 8):

As a structure for this kind of purposes, I suggest this:

### PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['action'])){
        if ($_POST['action'] == "function1") { func1(); }
        if ($_POST['action'] == "function2") { func2(); }
        if ($_POST['action'] == "function3") { func3(); }
        if ($_POST['action'] == "function4") { func4(); }
    }

    function func1(){
        //Do something here
        echo 'test';
    }
?>
```

### jQuery

```
var data = { action: 'function1' };

$.post(ajaxUrl, data, function(response) {
    if(response != "") {
        $('#SomeElement').html(response);
    }else{
        alert('Error, Please try again.');
    }
});
```

As mentioned, you can't call a PHP function directly from an AJAX call.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, yes you can.
Put all your functions in one php file and have the ajax pass as a parameter which one you want to call. Then with a switch or if structure, execute the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tfa_1117700').change(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        var v_token = "{{csrf_token()}}";
        $.post(
            "{{url('/each-child')}}",
            { dropdownValue: inputValue,_token:v_token },
            function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#each-child-html').html(data);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

php:

```
public function EachChild(Request $request)
{
    $html ="";
    for ($i=1; $i <= $request->dropdownValue; $i++)
    { 
        $html = $i;
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Please try to add some more context to your answer. Ask yourself: what does this do if I didn't read the question completely/or misunderstood it?