# PHP function doesn't work with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have some button and on click JS for it:

```
<button id="trigger">Send</button>
```

and JS to invoke simple action

```
$('#trigger').on("click", function(event){ 
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'functions.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {functionname: 'add', arguments: [1, 2]},

                        success: function (obj, textstatus) {
                            alert('test success');
                        },
                        complete: function (obj, textstatus) {
                            alert('test complete');
                        }
                    });
                });
```

In above ajax I put functions.php with other simple function:

```
<?php

$message = "PHP Funtion Alert";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

?>
```

But, I got only alert invoked from alert('test complete');
How invoke alert from PHP file?

PS. this is only example. In PHP file will be some DB functions.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Run the alert message spit out from the php file?

If so, you should just echo some text, then through jQuery alert the message.

Comment: I try to run PHP functions from functions.php file, when I click on the button

Answer (score 1):

You're expecting JSON, hence the

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Yet, you're returning a script tag?

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
```

And that's an error. What you want is to return valid **JSON**

```
$message = array("message" => "PHP Funtion Alert");
echo json_encode($message);
```

Then catch in the ajax function

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type     : "POST",
  url      : 'functions.php',
  dataType : 'json',
  data     : {
    data : 'to be sent'
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data.message);
}).fail(function() {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

Comment: can I use other dataType?

Comment: Also, I wound ommit the dataType: 'json'.

Why? Because then you'll need to use JSON.parse();

Comment: then I got: test success, and then test complete. I didnt get PHP Funtion Alert

Comment: function respond($result){
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    exit(json_encode($result));
  }

use this php function to send an array JSON response back to the client.

Comment: I wouldn't leave out the dataType. It tells you what you expect back - and if you expect json, then it should be set to json. But the PHP header should be set to json, and use `json_encode()` and return an array - alert it in the success

Comment: Now my functions looks like `<?php
function respond($result){ 
 header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8'); 
 $message = "PHP Funtion Alert";
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
 
 exit(json_encode($result)); 
} 
?>` and still doesn't work

Comment: You're not grasping it, you should **NOT** return a script tag at all. Firstly it's not JSON, and secondly jQuery's ajax doesn't execute the scripts anyway. Return JSON, and keep javascript on the clientside instead of echoing it back

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't understand it, but I am trying. I found similar question and solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341901/how-to-call-a-php-function-from-ajax but it doesn't work as well for me. I got only: _test complete_