# Trying to use javascript function to run mysql query for specific time when user click in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

When user click claim button, i want to run javascript function every 5 sec.
After i build up this code, and clicked the button but the script doesn't work. I'm not good at javascript at all. All i know is some php and mysql.

When user clicked claim button, the function send() should call payout() function and run this crul() function which is inside payout() function.
I don't know where i make mistake as i don't know much javascript.

this is the button function i build up. don't know if it wrong or not.

```
<button onclick="send()" class="btn-success"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Claim <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i></button>
<script>
function send() {
   setInterval(function(){ payout(); }, 5000);
}
</script>
```

This is the function payout()

```
function payout(){
    $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE wallets SET balance = balance - 1 WHERE wallet = '$wallet' " );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://faucethub.io/api/v1/send");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "api_key=$apikey&to=$wallet&currency=$shortcurrency&amount=$doge ");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

The result should be payout() function should send to that $wallet every 5 sec

Comment: call ajax and you can call php function, you cannot mix javascript and php function.

Comment: @Devsi Odedra can you give me some example about ajax calling? like link to learn

Comment: @Alvin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341901/how-to-call-a-php-function-from-ajax

Comment: Please do check the browser console for errors. JS can't execute php functions inside in it. Make AJAX(XMLHttpRequest https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) call to server  to do the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create one PHP file and move your PHP `payout()` in php file. second, you need to ajax call in the javascript interval.

> payout.php

```
//add the following code after your connection object
function payout(){
    $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE wallets SET balance = balance - 1 WHERE wallet = '$wallet' " );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://faucethub.io/api/v1/send");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "api_key=$apikey&to=$wallet&currency=$shortcurrency&amount=$doge ");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

> index.html

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="send()" class="btn-success"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Claim <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i></button>
<script>
function send() {
 setInterval(function () {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'payout.php',
   success: function (data) {
    console.log("payout attempt");
   },
  });
 }, 3000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I do like your answer, i make another page payout.php and paste that php function, do connect what i need in that file and in index.php, i also add the ajax code from your answer and also add <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> but when i click the button, nothing happen. Where did i miss?

Comment: Alvin, the code logs something to your browser's console if it succeeds. Press F12 to open your Developer Tools and view the console. Then press the button in your page. After a moment you should see either the "payout attempt" message, or an error (if it failed somehow). P.s. if you are going to start using JavaScript and AJAX then the Developer Tools are your best friend. I suggest you learn to use them, so you can debug your code effectively

Comment: @Alvin I have changed the code for `index.html` added snippet.

Comment: @ADyson it said send() is not defined. Why it said not define when i have the function for that button below. Omg.

Comment: @JellyFish Oh now in console log it has show payout attempt every 3 seconds, so that means javascript and ajax is success. But that php is not sending lol. Anyway thanks. I will figure out the rest :D

Comment: I would suspect the PHP shown above never gets executed since it's wrapped in a function and there is nothing to execute the function. The PHP script will run, but not do anything useful (unless this is only a small sample of it?). It's unclear where $wallet is defined as well. The PHP needs some alterations

Comment: why downvote man! need to create a PHP file on your folder, not in StackOverflow server. I think every user just give you step for solutions not doing done your work.

Comment: @JellyFish I don't downvote your answer i give up vote but my reputation is still low so it doesn't appear, someone with higher reputation give that to you. Sad to see this even yours answer help me :(

Comment: I didn't downvote either...I'd guess the downvoter might have been the same person who upvoted my comment about the PHP being a bit useless. Ideally a complete answer would resolve that too, but if Alvin is happy to work on that separately then I see no reason the answer shouldn't be accepted and upvoted generally. It solves the principal question which was posed, which was how to make contact with the server at regular intervals.

Comment: @ADyson It's fine, Thank you so much for replay. You are a good person!