# How to update a table simply by clicking a link in php and ajax

Tags: php

I have a messaging system in PHP, with the notification option. and the message status is by default status='0', which means the message is unread. what I want is, if receiver clicks on the sender profile(in chat area on the sidebar), the message status must update to status='1', which means the message has been read.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<a href="inbox?msgid=<?php echo $id;?>" style="width:90%">
                           <div class="row con_cont_list">
                               <div class="col-3">
                                   <img src="media/<?php echo $ProfileImg;?>" width="60px" height="60px" alt="">
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-9">
                                   <p><?php echo $FullName;?>
                                     <?php if($frnd_msgs_noti):?>
                                    <span class="badge badge-danger" style="border-radius:50%;"><?php echo $frnd_msgs_noti;?></span>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                  </p>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a Ajax request when the user clicks on the user profile, and send the userID with the ajax request so you can update the database record for that user. You won't have to open a link in new page or even reload the current page. In response of the Ajax request just remove the span showing unread messages.

Comment: can you please send me a ample code? while I'm new to ajax Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use Jquery library to handle ajax requests. First create a onClick event on your  tag then in the event send a ajax request to a php file.

Check this link for the sample. Instead of the button you have to use the  tag
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39342373/8173264