# How to convert PHP function to become called using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Edit: I am not directly trying call a PHP function using Javascript. The application routing will help frontend to hit the correct function.

I think my problem might have a simple solution, but I am not able to figure it out.

I have a bunch of PHP functions that output HTML. Something like:

```
<?php
function sample1($param1)
{
   //make DB query and loop and print HTML
?>
 <div class='some-class'>
    Some dynamic output here...
 </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

So like I said there are a bunch of such functions. And I want to call them using Ajax so that their values can be returned and I can print them/update DOM using Javascript. I know that I can update all the functions so that the HTML they generate can be stored into a string and then I can each that string. But is there an easier, cleaner solution to this problem?

Comment: AJAX being Javascript cannot call functions by their PHP names without some sort of conditional logic in the main of your PHP script responding to parameters sent it.

Comment: duplicate topic ,please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341901/how-to-call-a-php-function-from-ajax

Comment: @GetSet Those are already handled using the internal framework router etc.

Comment: Mentioning the *internal framework* this late in your question is kinda, well, late. Which framework?

Comment: @GetSet what does that matter? I said my internal router calls the function. I just want to know if there is a way to handle it such that if the call is via AJAX such as checking HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH value, then how to make these PHP functions return value instead of echoing.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not providing me the javascript ajax call i will focus on the php side.
I am using a simple get Ajax call:

```
$.get( "https://someKindofLink.php?callFunction=Hallo&doctor=who", function( data ) {
  alert( data );
});
```

On the php side we need to check is the function exists and the run it with all variables in $_GET:

```
if (isset($_GET['callFunction'])) {

    if(function_exists($_GET['callFunction'])){
        echo $_GET['callFunction']($_GET);
        exit;
    }
}

function hallo($params)
{
    return "Goodbye".$params['doctor'];
}
```

I would not advise this approach for security reasons but it should get the job done.

Comment: A very ingenious solution. But OP's claim `The application routing will help frontend to hit the correct function.` may necessitate its un-need.

Comment: Upvoted because OP was never going to. Cant anyway. Rep to low. I agree with you on the security concerns however your solution does illustrate the conditional logic on behalf of the server script.