# execute a php script on click of a html button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, button

I have a PHP code which does bunch of things so to keep things simple I have removed the unnecessary code from it.

In the below if block I need to create a pop up window with that `$message` on it and it should have `ok` and `cancel` button on it. Once I click `ok` button I need to execute some other php code in the same file if possible (or it can be another PHP file as well) and if I click `cancel` button then it should not do anything.

Below is my `test.php` file-

```
<?PHP
    // ..... some other code

    if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
        $text = "hello world";
        // create a pop up window with $message on it along with "ok" and "cancel" button
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('$text');</script>";
    }

    // ..... some other code
?>
```

I can have either `JS modal`, or an `HTML/CSS modal` anything works as long as I can have some actions on `ok` and `cancel` button. Is this possible to do? I tried looking around but not able to figure it out on how to do this.

**Update:**

Below is my updated `hello.php` file where I used Oliver suggestion. I tried with below code where I have a javascript function `secondUser` but it shows popup as `Sad :( - invalid session` once I click `ok` button.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function secondUser() {
    $.post( "ajax/test.php", function( data ) {
        if (data.success) {
            alert(data.message);
        } else {
            alert("Sad :( - invalid session");
        }
    });
}
</script>

<?PHP
    // ..... some other code

    if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
        $text = "hello world";
        // create a pop up window with $message on it along with "ok" and "cancel" button
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>if (confirm('$text')) { secondUser(); };</script>";
    }

    // ..... some other code
?>
```

Now I am not able to figure it out what is wrong in my above code? I just want to execute my `test.php` using ajax in my other php file.

Comment: so you make an Ajax call or submit a form or navigate to a link.

Comment: a codeblock in the same file? probably not, but in another php file you could, just put a simple ternay on the `confirm` and simply add a `location.href` pointing to it. if it's a post you'd need a form or make an xmlhttprequest using post.

Comment: @epascarello I am wondering if you can give an example how to do this ?

Comment: @user1950349 you mean a ternary? its just a shorthand if else `confirm() ? redirect : ''`

Comment: @kevin I meant to say if you can provide me an example in the fiddle https://3v4l.org/ Little bit code will work.

Comment: You may refer the following page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341901/how-to-call-a-php-function-from-ajax

Comment: @The KNVB Ok, I will have a look for sure. In my case there are 2 buttons (Ok and Cancel) involved in it. On clicking Ok button, I want to execute a php script and on clicking cancel, I don't want to do anything.

Comment: I use https://sweetalert.js.org/ for this. You can trigger this to open on page load if ther user is a pageadmin, and then when if they press okay or whatever you set your confirm text to be, then you get run a fetch command to trigger a script to run and do what you're after. Take a look at https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples for some examples.

Comment: The answer by Oliver below shows you one way to do this. Replace your `secondUser()` function with the answer's `attemptRequest()` function.  This calls your PHP code on the server.  Put whatever continuation you want in there.

Comment: @KScandrett yeah I tried that but it doesn't work for me. I updated my question with what I tried with Oliver example. Any thoughts what could be wrong? I added a comment to his answer as well.

Comment: what does `data` has in it ?

Comment: @Swati I am not sure about that. I copied the answer from Oliver which he has posted.

Comment: do `alert(data)` inside `function( data ) {..` and see what its giving

Comment: @Swati So I made the change and looks like whatever content is inside ajax/test.php is getting displayed on the popup and then this message `Sad :( - invalid session`. So maybe this line `if (data.success) {` is not getting evaluated looks like. Any thought why?

Comment: yes because you have put `echo "<script type='te..` only `echo` things which you need to return to ajax because whatever we `echo` will send back to ajax .

Comment: @Swati In my case I need to execute content of `test.php` file from `hello.php` file. That's all. I don't need to pass anything from `test.php` file to `hello.php`  file. How can I do this? Any thoughts?

Comment: @Swati are you around ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221375/discussion-between-swati-and-user1950349).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library to make a request using AJAX. First thing is registering the button.

```
<button id="cool-btn">My button</button>
```

Once you have the button running, you can add this script to the html or JS file.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cool-btn").click(function(){
        attemptRequest();
    });
});
</script>
```

Now you need to create a function called attemptRequest which makes an AJAX request for you to your PHP form.

```
function attemptRequest() {
    $.post( "ajax/test.php", function( data ) {
      if (data.success) {
          alert(data.message);
      } else {
          alert("Sad :( - invalid session");
      }
    });
}
```

Then you need to do the session checking in your PHP script called test.php in the ajax folder and return the appropriate data.

```
 $data = new stdClass();
 $data->success = false;
 $data->message = "";
 if (isset($_SESSION['pageadmin'])) {
     $data->message = "hello world";
     $data->success = true;
 }
 
 return json_encode($data);
```

Hope thats helpful :)

Comment: Hi Oliver, I tried your code and in the sources (inspect) section I am seeing the following [code](https://jsfiddle.net/9juw7pa3/1/)  
On clicking Ok button, it says `Sad :( - invalid session` and its not going inside `second_user.php` file although its going inside `secondUser()` javascript function.  


I am wondering what changes I need to make in the fiddle so that it goes inside `second_user.php` file.

Comment: Hi user (you should change your name :) ) 
Could you show me how your files are now laid out?

Comment: I created a fiddle already and it's the same setup I have. I just have only one php file `(admin.php)` and in that php file I have everything `(php+js)`. I know its not a best practice but I will try to change the structure later. 
I also updated the question with what I have tried.

Comment: I also updated my question with the details of what I tried.

Comment: Hi @user1950349 for this example could you please separate the PHP and JS/HTML files accordingly? I will gladly teach you to do it in one file in another question once we get the basics working. Apologies for the late response, ironically i usually am on stackoverflow on working days :)