# Get input value from database based on previous input

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, forms

I have a salary adding form, where I have to manually type in the rate for the morning and night shifts for every company. Every company have different rates. I want to make it as when the company's name is chosen, the rates should be retrieved from the database using php and fill in automatically so that the user only has to input how many days the labourer has worked. I'm not sure of how to implement this. Every company's rates are stored in a database.
How to do the jquery to make this idea work?

```
    <input type="text" name="name">  
     <div>
     <label>Morning Shift Rate: </label>
     <input type="number" name="morning_rate" 
     id="morning_rate">  

     <label> Days : </label>
     <input type="number" name="morning_day" id="morning_day">  
     </div>
                 
    <div>
    <label>Night Shift Rate: </label>
    <input type="number" name="night_rate" id="night_rate">  
                   
    <label> Day : </label>   
    <input type="number" name="night_day" id="night_day" >  
    </div>

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#name').click(function(){
            ????

           })        
    })
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must used AJAX call to request the datas from database.
But, you must have too a backend language (ex: PHP, Python...) because it's him who will retrieve the datas from database.
Example with jQuery:

```
submitForm = function(url, element) {
    const dataForm = element.serializeArray();
    let data = {'id': dataForm[0]}

    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url: url, // Your url to send the datas (the id in your view for example) at your backend
        data: data,
    }).then(response () {
        console.log(response.rate)
    })
}
```

I hope so help you.

Comment: Thanks. But could you give me an example of how to do it with PHP?

Comment: Yes, you have already a response in this website : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341901/how-to-call-a-php-function-from-ajax/39341939