# jquery event method to get input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, events, event-handling

I've used jquery to get an "id" as a value for an input according to a dropdown value. Now the problem is, I want to use the 'id' to insert value to some other inputs. I don't know which event method to be used. For testing, I used the keyup method to check if the code works, when I manually type in a number, it works. So the problem is with the event method I choose. Please give me some suggestions.

```
    //Get id
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#salary_eid').change(function() {
            var sid = $(this).val();
            var data_String = 'sid=' + sid;
            $.get('search1.php', data_String, function(result) {

                $.each(result, function(){
                  $('#can').val(this.c_id);
          
                    
                });
            });       
          });

      //display other information
      $('#can').change(function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            var data_String1 = 'id=' + id;
            $.get('search.php', data_String1, function(result1) {

                $.each(result1, function(){
                  $('#morning_rate').val(this.cMorning);
                    $('#night_rate').val(this.cNight);
                    $('#ot_rate').val(this.clientOt);
                    
                });
            });
        });
    });

 <label>Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="salary_eid" />
 <select id="salary_eid">
  <option>opt1</option>
  <option>opt2</option>
 </select>
    
 <input type="hidden" name="can" id="can" class="form-control" >
```

Comment: I am not too sure on what you are trying to achieve however it sounds like the on "change" event might do what you are looking for?

Comment: change event doesn't work as well @User1010

Comment: Are you able to provide some clarity on your problem?

Comment: Im able to display the id on the #can input but from there I cant use the ID which I get from the first jquery code to do the second code.

Comment: In the dropdown, a name will be chosen, then it should get Id from a different table and display it on #can input which is hidden, then using the #can, I should be able to display other information. So all this should happen when I chose the name

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the keyup() event from the id code, this will then work through a manual or jQuery edit,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>  
    //Get id
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#salary_eid').change(function() {
            var sid = $(this).val();
            $('#can').val(sid).keyup();
        });       
    });
    
    //display other information
    $(document).on('keyup', '#can', function() {
        console.log($(this).val())
    });
</script>

<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="salary_eid" />
<select id="salary_eid">
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="can" id="can" class="form-control" />
```

If you are going to hide the second input then I might suggest using a function instead without an input,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>  
    //Get id
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#salary_eid').change(function() {
            var sid = $(this).val();
            display_info(sid)
        });       
    });
    
    //display other information
    function display_info(value) {
        console.log(value)
    };
</script>

<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="salary_eid" />
<select id="salary_eid">
    <option>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But how can I do it without manually typing in the value for the #can input? The input will be hidden. so when I choose a name, it should automatically get the id to #can input then use the id to display information.

Comment: If the field is to be hidden then why use a different field? Why not trigger a function from the id function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259929/get-input-value-from-database-based-on-previous-input  - This is my problem