# Ajax call a php file in Opencart 2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, opencart

I want to ajax call a php file which i created system/helper which calls for a method of a model which adds a coupon in the database. the php file contains the following.

```
<?php
function coupon_for_acumba() {
            $this->load->model('total/coupon');

            echo $this->model_total_coupon->coupon_test();
        }
```

I created a js file which makes the ajax call when a form is submitted. The script in the file is the following

```
let acumbaForm = document.querySelector('#form-acm_28955');
                acumbaForm.addEventListener('submit', function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {if (document.querySelector('.succes-alert-form-acm')) {
                        $.ajax({

                                url : '/system/helper/acumba.php',
                                type : 'POST',
                                success : function (result) {
                                console.log (result); // Here, you need to use response by PHP file.
                },
                    error : function () {
                        console.log ('error');
            }

                    });
                }}, 2000)
                    
                })
```

finally i called this js file in catalog/controller/common/header.php with $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/test1.js');

The problem is that everytime i submit the form i get an error message from the ajax call. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong please?

Comment: at first. you should always ask back what kind of error you get back, in this case you only know there is an error. Have you checked the console and see if you even get a response from the file.

Comment: In the console i get  the message POSThttps://www.margaritari.gr/public_html/system/helper/acumba.php [HTTP/3 404 Not Found 196ms] and then a message saying error

Comment: `404` means litterly your file and url is not found..  remove the `public_html` out of your url and try again. public_html is a server folder that is often ignored since your `index.php` file is within that

Comment: ok wait that worked. no error this time. now the console log retuns <empty string>

Comment: Well, you technically dont tell to do anything to the file, be honest. You say, execute this file, but you dont tell it to run set function or submit any kind of data on things to happen. Hence your empty sting. If you echo in the file "test" outside of the function, you ll see it returns that, but a function wont fire on it self. You ll have to tell it to do that,

Comment: what should i do to make it fire?

Comment: call the function in the file.... just like you would execute any other function in a file. before or after you function, you just simply put `coupon_for_acumba();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a php function from ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341901/how-to-call-a-php-function-from-ajax)

Comment: It didn't help me unfortunately everything i did resulted in [HTTP/3 500 Internal Server Error ]. I have no idea what to do now

Comment: 500 means most of the time there is an error in your php file. check your error log if turned on.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart doesn't allow call PHP files directly from system folder (check .htaccess file in system folder). Try to open https://yoursite/system/helper/acumba.php, You'll get 403 Forbidden. You have to use a route to call a method.

```
url : '/system/helper/acumba.php', // wrong
```

You have to modify /catalog/controller/extension/total/coupon.php and put in your method, then call this way in your JS file.

```
url : 'index.php?route=extension/total/coupon/coupon_for_acumba',
```